# Homework questions allowed?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, solution-verification

I'm learning set theory independently at the moment and using a book that doesn't have a solutions manual. Under these conditions, is it okay if I make a thread asking if my solution is correct?

Thanks

Comment: If you show work, no one should complain. They could always down vote for whatever reason though.

Comment: Under these circumstances, tagging as [tag:homework] even seems superfluous. Using [tag:solution-verification] may be warranted, though. But I see no harm in such posts.

Comment: Analysis Incarnate: Props for asking in advance. What you are planning should be ok. @Lord_Farin: Welcome back! [While you were sleeping](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what/16438#16438)

Comment: Cheers everyone

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Woah, that's a big change I've missed. Thanks for pointing it out :). Also, thanks for the welcome; much appreciated :).

Comment: [Do none of these answer your question?!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework) Asking homework questions might be okay, asking questions that have already been asked dozens of times is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as long as you show your work and *make sure the question hasn't been asked before*!

That is, surf the "set-theory" tag a while, and maybe you'll find answers to your questions. Also, exploit the search button.